# R: Check to see if coordinates fall inside/outside of a shapefile polygon?

Tags: r

I have one shape file and a dataframe.

The dataframe I am working with is this:

```
df <- data.frame(
    name = c("point 1","point 2","point 3","point 4"),
    judge_whether_within_shp = c('','','',''),
    lon = c(101.1,102.3,105.8,104.6),
    lat = c(103.5,106.2,107.8,109.6)
)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eBYK.png)

I making a polygon shp.file in Arcgis and read it in R:
`shape <- st_read("E:\\DATA\\select_area", layer = "New_Shapefile")`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sv6kx.png)

I want to check if coordinates fall inside/outside of a shapefile polygone, and add 1 or 0 in judge_whether_within_shp column.

I use sf package st_join() function but is not work.
Any idea?? Can someone help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make points from your data frame and use `st_intersects`:

```
df = st_as_sf(df, coords=c("lon","lat"), crs=4326)
df$inshape = lengths(st_intersects(df, shape) > 0)
```

`st_intersects` returns a list of the rows of the shape that each point is in, because a point could be in more than one shape, so the test is if the list element is non-empty.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try it! Sorry for not giving you timely feedback, my computer broke down last week.